# How can I leave the loop if no records are part of the if statement?

Tags: coldfusion, cfloop

Below code works, but I would like to show 'no records' message if 
 `<cfif GetResults2.csedept_id eq aFieldValue>`  has no records for that value. I have tried to put a counter on, but I just can't get it to show 'no records' and not show the 
 `<thead> <th>Name</th> <th>Positive Comment</th> <th>Negative Comment</th></thead>` heading of the table if there are no records.

**How can I show "No Records" and hide the table head if the results come back empty**

Right now if the result comes back empty it will say "no results"(correct) and display the header(incorrect).

```
<cfset counter3= 0>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tablecolors">
<h2> Comments </h2>
 <thead> <th>Name</th> <th>Positive Comment</th> <th>Negative Comment</th></thead>
  <cfloop  query="GetResults2">
    <cfif GetResults2.csedept_id eq aFieldValue>     

      <tr>
        <td nowrap="nowrap">#emp_namefirst# #Left(emp_namelast, 1)#  </td>
        <td>#Replace(commentpositive, emp_namefirst, "<B>" & emp_namefirst & "</B>")#</td>
        <td>#Replace(commentnegative, emp_namefirst, "<B>" & emp_namefirst & "</B>")#</td>
      </tr>
<cfelse><p>no records</p>

    </cfif>
  </cfloop>    
    </table>
```

UPDATE: Just to add I do have another query above like @FRANK said that does pretty much the same things for example:

```
'<cfloop query="GetEmployeeTotals3">
        <cfif GetEmployeeTotals3.csedept_id eq aFieldValue> '
```

here is the query:

```
select GetResults.* , GetEmployees.emp_namefirst, GetEmployees.emp_namelast
    from GetResults, GetEmployees
    where employee = emp_id
    order by csedept_id
```

so all the solutions above that I tried won't work.

Comment: Run a loop before your table and set a flag to true if you have results then exit the loop. Use that flag to determine what to display.

Comment: @matt how can i set a flag? can you tell me  a example that i can research? thanks

Comment: Your prose only makes sense if either the GetResults2 query only has one row, or the csedept_id is the same for every record.  Otherwise you can have a situation where you both want and don't want the headers.  Please clarify.

Comment: The GetResults2 query should have the criteria in the WHERE clause to filter the results.  This method strikes me as a "SELECT * FROM TABLE" and filter the results in CFML.  If the <cfquery> code is provided someone could show you how to modify the query.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a query of queries to whittle the result set down to just the values you care about first.  Then you can easily check, the recordcount before outputting the table at all.

Alternatively, loop first and build up the results with cfsavecontent, then check to see if you found any prior to getting to the table bits.

Comment: umm not sure how i would do that, since im displaying before this #csedept_name# from a query and depending on this query i get the names of the department data , in total im using 4 different query

Comment: Your original code example does not contain any csedept_name variable, so that doesn't give me any information at all.  Perhaps you can post all 4 queries so we can understand your scenario.  Still, I think my answer holds true-- you only care about a subset of data, so use QofQ to pull out just that data.  Note, this would add more query objects into your code.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Updated answer after question was clarified

You'll need to move your `cfif` to include your table head when checking for records. If the check comes back with a record count, then output the table head as well as the results, otherwise output "no results". I've written two versions below, one is utilizing the `cfoutput` instead of a loop (just personal preference) and one with your loop if you wish to keep it.

I added Dan's `listfind()` `valuelist()` combo...so give him credit for that.

**Edit Edit** so this is the super-strength/ultra-correct awesome solution with the 'I-am-tired-of-editing-this-answer-50-times-to-get-OP-an-answer', with bonus shameless theft from Dan's answer above/below. Or where ever we ending up order-wise.

```
<table>
<cfif getresults2.recordcount AND ListFind(ValueList(GetResults2.csedept_id), aFieldValue)> 
<tr>
    <th>name</th> 
    <th>positive comment</th> 
    <th>negative comment</th>
</tr>

<cfoutput query="getresults2">
<tr>
    <td nowrap="nowrap">#emp_namefirst# #left(emp_namelast, 1)#  </td>
    <td>#replace(commentpositive, emp_namefirst, "<b>" & emp_namefirst & "</b>")#</td>
    <td>#replace(commentnegative, emp_namefirst, "<b>" & emp_namefirst & "</b>")#</td>
</tr>
</cfoutput> 

<cfelse>
<tr colspan="3">
    <td><p>no records</p></td>
</tr>
</cfif>
</table>
```

If you have your `cfoutput` somewhere in your code (where we cannot see), then here is your `cfloop` back, simply replace this where I have the `cfoutput` in the snippet above.

```
<cfloop query="getresults2">
  <tr>
    <td nowrap="nowrap">#emp_namefirst# #left(emp_namelast, 1)#  </td>
    <td>#replace(commentpositive, emp_namefirst, "<b>" & emp_namefirst & "</b>")#</td>
    <td>#replace(commentnegative, emp_namefirst, "<b>" & emp_namefirst & "</b>")#</td>
  </tr>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: This completely ignores his `<cfif GetResults2.csedept_id eq aFieldValue>` check within his loop

Comment: @MattBusche You absolutely addressed that. For my approach I simplified the problem to records or no records. So then I was pretty sure he was looking for something like .recordcount (or anything that is not zero to start the loop but then got botched in an incremental loop issue). At its essence (before it was edited), their were concept and structure problems that were compounding on the OP.

Comment: yeah, the question is pretty vauge, but that if statement has always been within his loop

Comment: @MattBusche I agree. but look at the variables too.  getResults2 and counter3.  That means this page most likely has getResults and getResults2 and counter and counter2... Which means there are possibly queries (plural) that 'probably' do similar things. There is more here than meets the eye.

Comment: @frank You are correct there are queries that do pretty much the same thing but your solution does not work because i do need the afiledvalue part

Comment: @user3591637 I edited my answer...give it a try and see if it works for you now.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. You'll have to set a flag of `showRecords` that will determine if you should show the headers.

```
<cfset showRecords = false>
<cfloop query="GetResults2">
  <cfif GetResults2.csedept_id eq aFieldValue> 
    <cfset showRecords = true>
    <cfbreak>
  </cfif>
</cfloop>

<h2> Comments </h2>
<cfif showRecords>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tablecolors">
  <thead> <th>Name</th> <th>Positive Comment</th> <th>Negative Comment</th></thead>
  <cfloop query="GetResults2">
    <cfif GetResults2.csedept_id eq aFieldValue> 
      <tr>
        <td nowrap="nowrap">#emp_namefirst# #Left(emp_namelast, 1)#  </td>
        <td>#Replace(commentpositive, emp_namefirst, "<B>" & emp_namefirst & "</B>")#    </td>
        <td>#Replace(commentnegative, emp_namefirst, "<B>" & emp_namefirst & "</B>")#</td>
      </tr>
    </cfif>
  </cfloop>    
  </table>
<cfelse>
  <p>no records</p>
</cfif>
```

Comment: No real need for the flag, the question is posed specifically for an If/Then statement if records exist or not. You can remove your flag and calls against it, move your `GetResults2.csedept_id eq aFieldValue` into the `cfif` statement below and you have thinner, equally effective code for a simple solution.

Comment: @Dylan that doesn't solve the issue of the header showing if there are no results. His original query may contain rows he doesn't care about.

Comment: Yes it does, replace your `cfif showRecords` with `cfif getresults2.recordcount` and you can remove your entire flag system. Check Frank's answer above for clarity

Comment: @Dylan what if nothing matches the if statement? Then you have a header with no results.

Comment: ^ Edited previous response to clear up what I was trying to say

Comment: @Dylan once again, what if `<cfif GetResults2.csedept_id eq aFieldValue>` returns no matches? Then you have a header and no results

Answer (score 0):

While your question is still unclear, this might be what you want.

```
<cfif ListFind(ValueList(GetResults2.csedept_id), aFieldValue)> 
your existing code to display results in a table
<cfelse>
<p>No Records Found</p>
```

Note that this:

```
ListFind(ValueList(GetResults2.csedept_id), aFieldValue)
```

will execute and return false even if GetResults2 has no records at all.

**Edit starts here**

Based on this comment, "well if it only appears on some then display does but to those who do not match then ignore" change your existing code to something like:

```
<cfquery name = "q3" dbtype = "query">
select * from GetResults2
where csedept_id = #aFieldValue#
<cfquery>

<table>
column header row
<cfoutput query="q3">
data rows
</cfoutput>
<table>
```

The initial construct at the start of this answer still applies.

Comment: @ With the changes I made and modify the code a little it , mix it up with your solution I got it to display the output i wanted, will still look into maybe making this more efficient but that would probably mean making more changes to alot of my code

Comment: shouln't the listfind go though all the records it is only going to the first it finds and display?

Comment: The listfind will essentially tell you whether or not aFieldValue appears in the csedept_id field of any of the records in your query results.  The part of your question that is still unclear is, what do you want to display if aFieldValue appears in some, but not all the records?

Comment: well if it only appears on some then display does but to those who do not match then ignore. It seems is only looking at the first record that it finds then it exit, that why i was not sure if it actually goes thought them all.